# Why disable powerups?

Tags: temple-run

I noticed after playing Temple Run **1** for a while and fully upgrading my powerups that there's an option for disabling powerups. My question is how game mechanics handle this decision, and I have a couple theories:

1. Powerups in general  have a constant chance of appearing at specific intervals in a run, and disabling a powerup allows other powerups to occur more often. e.g., constant chance of 10% in general, so 2.5% chance for magnet, invisibility, boost, and mega coin, and disabling one of them allows the remaining 3 a 3.33% chance of occuring.
2. Each powerup has a specific constant chance of appearing at specific intervals, (e.g., 2.5%) and thus the overall chance of any occuring is 10%, and disabling one of them reduces the overall probability to 7.5%.

I can see why disabling powerups would be advantageous in the first scenario if you have a preference for specific powerups, but I have no way of determining which of these mechanics are what's happening. Can anyone verify either of these, or state if there's actually a different mechanic than either of those going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the company updated the game itself, they also released what's the point of it.
And yes, your first theory is correct.

> > In the Android & iPhone/iPad game “Temple Run,” the last upgrade for each of the four powerups costs 25,000 coins. These are listed:
>
> Allow disabling Mega Coin. Allow disabling Coin Magnet. Allow
>   disabling Invisibility. Allow disabling Boost. What do these upgrades
>   do? Should you buy them?
>
> These upgrades give you the option of turning OFF whichever powerup
>   you bought the upgrade for. That means you won’t see it appear in
>   actual gameplay. Once you get the “Allow Disabling…” upgrade, you can
>   always turn the powerup back on if you choose. The Store will allow
>   you to freely switch between enabling or disabling the powerup at no
>   additional charge.
>
> So why would you want to turn any of the powerups off? Well, the Mega
>   Coin for example doesn’t give you all that many coins. For that
>   reason, I disable the Mega Coin so I can get one of the other, more
>   powerful powerups more often.
>
> Also, if you are focusing on one specific objective, for example, the
>   “10k Runner” to run 10,000 meters, you may want to enable ONLY the
>   Boost powerup and leave everything else disabled. That way, all
>   powerups you find in the game will be Boosts, and you can get a better
>   run distance.